# How can i match a word in a string which has two same words before it using JavaScript regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example: "**foo foo bar word**", it will match the word:"**bar**", because "**bar**" has two same words "**foo**" ahead it . 
It seems that javascript regular expression doesn't support **Zero-width positive lookbehind** method. So how can I find an Alternative method to solve this problem.

Comment: You could do something like `\b(\w+) \1 (\w+)` which will capture "bar" in group 2.

Comment: You do not need any positive lookbehind. `/(\w+)\W+\1\W+(\w+)/` is enough, then grab Group 2 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can using regex [back reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) and use [regex.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) obtain the results.

```
describe('back reference', () => {
   it('matching with regex.exec()', () => {
    let source = `foo foo bar word ooh ooh ooh yes`;

    let regex = /(\w+)(?:\W+\1)+\W+(\w+)/g;

    expect(regex.exec(source)[2]).toEqual('bar');
    expect(regex.exec(source)[2]).toEqual('yes');
    expect(regex.exec(source)).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple possible solution.

```
//get an array of words.
var words = string.split(' ');

//loop  through the words
for(var i = 2; i < words.length; i++){
   //lets skip the first 2 words.
   if(words[i-1] === words[i-2]){
     //the last 2 words are equal.
     //your match is here.
   }
}
```

you could also keep track of a lastWord variable and check it against that to have less array lookups. but i think this is generally regarded as an easier to read solution than regex, but less so, memory wise.